# PFQuery returning objects where object's relation matches all conditions

Tags: objective-c, search, parse-platform, pfrelation

Working on an iPhone app with Parse DB backend I'm trying to implement a **search** functionality using search **tokens**. I read Parse's white papers on scalable search, relations vs. pointers, documentation, various SO / Parse.com discussions, etc. - unfortunately couldn't find any similarity to my problem.

I'm using a class `SearchToken` where I'm storing **unique** sanitised tokens and I have a `PFRelation *tokenRelation` in related class `Article` (*every article can have multiple search tokens; every token can be related to multiple articles*).

I'm trying to form a query that finds all objects from `Article` class that contain all searched tokens (e.g. `@"token1", @"token2"`). Unfortunately `whereKey:containsAllObjectsInArray:` doesn't work on `PFRelation` attributes which further complicates things for me.

An easy option would be to convert that `PFRelation` attribute to an array of pointers but I know that the number of associated tokens can exceed everywhere-mentioned limit of 100 objects so I'm bit hesitant here.

My question is: **is there any other way of querying objects matching all conditions in related objects (via `PFRelation`) or is there any better way of implementing tokenised search feature?**

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the array of pointers, because I assume there is a maximum number of tokens that can be set on one article. (AFAIK the limit is 1k [Parse Docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/limit) ) Parse says it makes sense if you know the max number (e.g postal codes). See [Relationships in parse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x70G_LPlW60)

If an array of pointers is not a possible solution for you, I'd solve the n:m relation with your own class  (e.g. HasToken or TokenRelationship) instead of PFRelation (or Array of pointers).

```
@interface TokenRelationship : PFObject <PFSubclassing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) Article article;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SearchToken searchToken;
@end
```

Then perform a query on TokenRelationship with a subquery using `whereKey:matchesQuery:`.

Nevertheless you can reach the limit of 1k. So both solutions have their limits. I hope that parse introduces where-key constraints on forein-key pointers like: `whereKey:@"searchToken.tokenString" equalTo:@"token1"` or they do away with the 1k limit on sub/inner-queries. Otherwise n:m relation queries are likely to exceed the limit.